# Angular Material2 use optionSelectionChanges property of MdSelect directive IE11

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material2

In my application i have a material2 select dropdown widget with few options.

**app.component.html**

```
<md-select placeholder="Choose an option" [(ngModel)]="myOption" 
           (optionSelectionChanges)="setOptionValue(myOption)">
  <md-option value="value1"> Option-1 </md-option>
...
</md-select>
```

I'm trying to call `'setOptionValue()'` whenever the option value changes.

**./app.component.ts**

```
..
myOption: string;
constructor(..){
   this.myOption = 'value1'; 
}
setOptionValue(option: any) {
    console.log(option)
}
```

There are no official documentation on how to use `optionSelectionChanges` property.

Comment: They really lack documentation. See this answer to understand how to use `optionSelectionChanges` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730922/1791913

Comment: thank you for your answer. i get `Unable to get property 'setFirstItemActive' of undefined or null reference` when i select the dropdown. what could be the possible solution to this? This happens only in IE11

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet of what i do:

```
<md-select class="periodselect" [(ngModel)]="BTWPeriodMonths" (ngModelChange)="outBTWPeriod.emit(BTWPeriodMonths)" placeholder="BTW periode">
      <md-option [value]="1">
        1 maand
      </md-option>
      <md-option [value]="3">
        Kwartaal
      </md-option>
      <md-option [value]="12">
        Jaar
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
```

You can also use (optionSelectionChanges)="setOptionValue($event)" with $event